# How to interpret this memory usage in Python?

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

I have written this code in a Jupyter Notebook for deep learning purposes:

```
X_train_imbalanced=[]
Y_train_imbalanced=[]
# create sequences
look_back=50
for k in range (0, len (train_list)):
    print (k)
    #print (len(train_list[k].iloc[:,1:nb_features-1].values))
    temp_data, temp_target= create_dataset (train_list[k].iloc[:,1:nb_features-1].values, train_list[k].iloc[:,nb_features-1].values, look_back)
#     print (len(temp_data))
#     print (len (temp_data[0]))
#     print (len (temp_target))
    if (k==0) :
        X_train_imbalanced=temp_data
        Y_train_imbalanced=temp_target
    else :
        %memit X_train_imbalanced=np.concatenate((X_train_imbalanced,temp_data), axis=0)
        Y_train_imbalanced=np.concatenate((Y_train_imbalanced,temp_target), axis=0)
```

where `temp_data` is a 3-D array of size `(?, 50,22)` where `?` varies from one iteration to another but is quite big (around 30000).

When I am running the code, it becomes very slow at around the 20th iteration and here is what `%memit` gives :

```
1
peak memory: 1221.69 MiB, increment: 309.11 MiB
2
peak memory: 1313.96 MiB, increment: 366.71 MiB
3
peak memory: 1370.51 MiB, increment: 358.19 MiB
4
peak memory: 1396.97 MiB, increment: 370.20 MiB
5
peak memory: 1666.82 MiB, increment: 509.88 MiB
6
peak memory: 1803.96 MiB, increment: 517.50 MiB
7
peak memory: 1738.25 MiB, increment: 583.27 MiB
8
peak memory: 1788.33 MiB, increment: 781.89 MiB
9
peak memory: 2107.31 MiB, increment: 966.23 MiB
10
peak memory: 2060.38 MiB, increment: 903.95 MiB
11
peak memory: 2210.77 MiB, increment: 1000.03 MiB
12
peak memory: 2179.66 MiB, increment: 915.61 MiB
13
peak memory: 2267.32 MiB, increment: 1683.86 MiB
14
peak memory: 2455.46 MiB, increment: 1156.93 MiB
15
peak memory: 2508.21 MiB, increment: 938.65 MiB
16
peak memory: 3160.77 MiB, increment: 1485.71 MiB
17
peak memory: 3416.46 MiB, increment: 1600.22 MiB
18
peak memory: 3512.63 MiB, increment: 1616.89 MiB
19
peak memory: 3725.57 MiB, increment: 2344.89 MiB
20
peak memory: 3776.23 MiB, increment: 1777.52 MiB
21
peak memory: 3835.47 MiB, increment: 1702.66 MiB
22
peak memory: 3949.54 MiB, increment: 3490.01 MiB
```

However, I have some difficulties to interpret that in practice... I have a RAM of 6GB, does the above results can explain why the code becomes slow to run and nearly crashes the machine ?

How to avoid this ? Is there way to optimize the code ? Or is it better to run the code not on my laptop but on a bigger infrastructure ?

I am a bit confused on what I should do...

Comment: `x  = np.concatenate((x, y))` creates copies; see if you can use `np.append(x, y)` instead.

Comment: @AKX It does not give better resiults, unfortunately